Week day error when using timeVariation function in R
I am using library openair in R to create a timeVariation plot that should look like the image.

Anyway I am getting the following error and I don't know why it appears
Error in `mutate()`: ℹ In argument: `wkday = wday(date, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)`. Caused by error in `factor()`: ! invalid 'labels'; length 6 should be 1 or 7
I tried with some openair data and it remains. The code for that example is:
library(openair)
mary <- importAURN(site = "my1", year = 2000)

timeVariation(mary, 
              pollutant = 'no2',
              type = 'month')

Does anyone know why is it happening? Thanks in advance.

I don't have that package so I don't know what your mary looks like, but it sounds like this should be a new bug report since both the input data and the erring-code are completely internal to the package.

According to the doc: The argument for type:
"Can either be default or site. If site is chosen then the data frame must contain a field named site. " https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openair/versions/0.3-9/topics/timeVariation
